# Karate Gatling Report Customization

Tags: scala, customization, karate

Is it possible to customize Karate gatling report from scala file itself? Can we add anything to scala file in order to control how gatling report appears or what content or graph to be displayed in the gatling report.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. There is typically no reason to change it, it has been designed by experts in the field of performance-testing.

That said, all the data is available in `simulation.log` for you to create your own report. Also note that there are ways to connect gatling to things like grafana etc, you can search for all that, nothing specific to Karate.